# Add the same method to multiple classes

Tags: ruby

I have some code that calculates the nth root of a number. Right now, that method only works on Fixnum, because I defined it inside the Fixnum class. It would be very easy to just do

```
class Float
    #same code as was in Fixnum
end
```

but that seems unneccessary. I have no idea how to dynamically call classes. I tried:

```
classes = [Fixnum, Float]
classes.each do |x|
    x.instance_eval do
        def root(pow)
            return self ** (1/pow.to_f)
        end
    end
end
```

but that did not work. How do I do this?
**Note**: After posting, I realized this might be a better fit for Programmers.SE, as it is theoretical, as well as single-problem based. Feel free to migrate accordingly...

Comment: Note that in the above `return` is not necessary (and is non-idiomatic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant part of the class hierarchy looks like this:

- [`Numeric`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html)

  - [`Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html)

    - Older versions had `Fixnum` and `Bignum` as subclasses of `Integer`.
  - [`Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html)
  - [`Rational`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html)

So patch your change into Numeric to cover them all at once:

```
class Numeric
  def root(pow)
    return self ** (1/pow.to_f)
  end
end
```

Then you can do these things:

```
>> 11.root(2) # Integer
=> 3.3166247903554
>> 2.18.root(3) # Float
=> 1.296638256974172
>> Rational(23, 42).root(6) # Rational
=> 0.9045094132598528
>> 2**1000.root(42) # Integer
=> 2.2638347236157763
```

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to use #class_eval:

```
classes = [Fixnum, Float]
classes.each do |x|
    x.class_eval do
        def root(pow)
            return self ** (1/pow.to_f)
        end
    end
end
```

See [this blog post](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2009/01/09/fun-with-rubys-instance_eval-and-class_eval/) as a reference.

Alternatively, you could create a module and include it into each class:

```
module MyRoot
  def root(pow)
    return self ** (1/pow.to_f)
  end
end

class Fixnum
  include MyRoot
end

class Float
  include MyRoot
end
```

I lean towards the latter. It's clearer what you're doing and allows one-off additions as well.

Comment: +1 for being right in general, but -1 for not having the Right answer for the actual need: inherit from `Numeric`.